# React router V6 how do I set up Route path with multiple :id, some optional

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using `react-router@6` and have a Route that I used in V5. Routes of a vehicles which always accepts one parameter (:id = vehicle id). But also has a second parameter (:date = string in DD-MM-YYYY format that is optional):

```
<Route path='/vehicles/routes/:id/:date?'>
  <VehicleRoutesPage requiresRole={[1,2,3]} requiresAuth="vehicle_routes" />
</Route>
```

I am trying to convert this into `react-router@6`. It is working up to a point - meaning it will work only with ID but not with the optional date parameter. With the optional date parameter I am redirected to the not found page.

```
<Route path="/vehicles/routes/:id" element={<VehiclesRoutesPage />} />
```

This will get me to the not found page. Both with the optional date parameter and without it:

```
<Route path="/vehicles/routes/:id/:date?" element={<VehiclesRoutesPage />} />
```

This will always get me to the routes page but no parameters are ever red:

```
<Route path="/vehicles/routes/*" element={<VehiclesRoutesPage />} />
```

Mentioning all above (working or partially working) I am always getting error in the console:
`GET http://localhost:3000/vehicles/routes/undefined 404 (Not Found)`
Even with the simple :id only case where the page gets correctly displayed:
`<Route path="/vehicles/routes/:id" element={<VehiclesRoutesPage />} />`

It is worth to mention that my components are wrapped in withRouter HOC:

```
import {
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams
} from 'react-router-dom'

function withRouter(Component: any) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props: any) {
    let location = useLocation();
    let navigate = useNavigate();
    let params = useParams();
    return (
      <Component
        {...props}
        router={{ location, navigate, params }}
      />
    );
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}

export default withRouter
```

This is so I can actually access location, params and navigate properties which I need.

I am pretty sure I am overlooking something but I am unable to see what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Have you tried nesting the `:date` in another route ?
`<Route path='/:id'><Route path='/:date'></Route></Route>`

Comment: @RiadhAdrani no I have not tried that. How would I actually link my component (element in this case) with that solution?

Comment: @RiadhAdrani I have tried it now and it seems to be working:     <Route path='/vehicles/routes/:id' element={<VehiclesRoutesPage />}>
      <Route path='/vehicles/routes/:id/:date' element={<VehiclesRoutesPage />} />
    </Route>

Comment: @RiadhAdrani however I am still getting that weird error`GET http://localhost:3000/vehicles/routes/undefined 404 (Not Found)` even with everything working now

Comment: @RiadhAdraniOK so I can see what is going on here with the error. All the :id must be embedded otherwise they produce the weird 404 not found error. What I can see however is that even with embed the optional paramter :date still produces the 404 error

Comment: @RiadhAdranid @RiadhAdrani so after embedding it like this: `    <Route path='/vehicles/routes' element={<VehiclesRoutesPage />}>
      <Route path='/vehicles/routes/:id' element={<VehiclesRoutesPage />}>
        <Route path='/vehicles/routes/:id/:date' element={<VehiclesRoutesPage />} />
      </Route>
    </Route>` it works, but I am getting still this weird error: GET http://localhost:3000/vehicles/routes/63/undefined 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any particular issue with the route:

```
<Route
  path="/vehicles/routes/:id/:date?"
  element={<VehiclesRoutesPage />}
/>
```

What I suspect is the issue is that you are using an *older* version of `react-router-dom@6`. Optional path parameters were reintroduced to `react-router-dom` starting with v6.5.0. As of this posting v6.8.1 is the current version. Provided you bump your dependency to at least `react-router-dom@6.5` the route with optional path parameters should function as you are expecting.

[image: Edit react-router-v6-how-do-i-set-up-route-path-with-multiple-id-some-optional]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your routes should be of this form :

```js
    <BrowserRouter>
      ...
        <Routes>
          ...
          <Route path="/vehicule" element={<Vehicule />}>
            <Route path="/vehicule/routes" element={<VRoutes />}>
              <Route path="/vehicule/routes/:id" element={<Id />}>
                <Route path="/vehicule/routes/:id/:date" element={<Date />} />
              </Route>
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      ...
    </BrowserRouter>
```

just replace dummy elements with your components.

---

Use `Outlet` to render nested route, for example:

```js
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

export function Vehicule() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Outlet></Outlet>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and of course you can `useParams` in the nested routes:

```js
const {id,date} = useParams();
```

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-v6-forked-khv9iv?file=/src/App.js) to test it out and let me know if something went wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The only issue with that code is that I am using same component for all the options. I just red that optional parameters has been reintroduced in the 6.5 version so I have updated my package and it works. The only weird thing I am constantly getting is that 404 error. Why is it there if the page renders I can not say...

Comment: Which bundler are you using ? `Webpack`, `Vite`... with `Webpack`, it tries to fetch the html file from the address which could result in that error.

Comment: I am using Webpack, it came with the react - typescript installation. Should I just ignore those errors?

Comment: Well, you can, but you also can modify the webpack config to fix the problem. Did you use `create-react-app` to generate the project for you? if so the webpack config are inside the react-scripts package in node_modules. By the way, I recommend using `Vite`.